# ESLint - Getting error - 'expect' is assigned a value but never used

Tags: javascript, eslint, supertest

```
const supertest = require('supertest-as-promised');  
const expect = require('chai').expect;  

const request = supertest(process.env.BASE_URI);`
```

I am getting this ESLint error:

> 'expect' is assigned a value but never used'

for `expect` statement. What changes could I make to get rid of these errors from my all `.js` files?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558795/nice-way-to-get-rid-of-no-unused-expressions-linter-error-with-chai

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558795/nice-way-to-get-rid-of-no-unused-expressions-linter-error-with-chai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encountering the `no-unused-vars` rule from ESLint. You can read more about that from their [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars).

The reason ESLint is warning about you about this is that you've declared `expect` and assigned a value to it.

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
```

**However you haven't used it anywhere.**

To get rid of the error you need to use `expect` somewhere.

```
describe('A test', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    expect(something).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: The example given as improvement – `expect(something).to.be.true` – triggers the ESLint warning [`no-unused-expressions`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions).

Answer (score -1):

Can use this in .eslint file

```
{
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "local", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]
  }
}
```

For more info check this link
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars