# Even though my mocha test cases are using should , eslint still warns about it?

Tags: node.js, chai, eslint

I'm using mocha and chai.should assertion library to unit test my OSS npm module. But eslint [v3.18.0^] warns at the should declaration in the code about it not being used

`const should = chai.should();`

**Lint Warning** 
'should' is assigned a value but never used.

We have mocha as an environment in the .eslintrc. This warning appears despite there being atleast seven assertion statements in my test file like below that have "should" in them.

```
return sampleModule.getSomeFunction('dummy_accesss_token', 'dummy_event_id').should.eventually.be.eql([]);
```

I'm aware of the following [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558795/nice-way-to-get-rid-of-no-unused-expressions-linter-error-with-chai) issue which talks about other assertion statments which are never declared while a reply[which was not even declared as the answer] to the query had someone created a plugin to overcome this.

But my basic premise , isnt this a bug in eslint? Atleast "should" should :-) not be flagged since its being used in code [multiple times in my case].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> isnt this a bug in eslint?

No, because you *are* not using the variable called `should`.

You're using a getter called `should` that `chai.should()` adds to `Object.prototype`, but that's not the same as using the *variable*.

You can still use that variable, for instance like this:

```
should.exist(...);
should.not.exist(...);
```

But you're probably not doing that.

So to get rid of the warning, don't do this:

```
const should = chai.should();
```

But do this:

```
chai.should();
```

Comment: Thanks @robertklep . Reading your comment and this is further reinforced in the chai guide http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/