# how to fix error for "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I have couple line of code to use chai library but I get this error *Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression* on *expect(validTime(t)).to.be.true;* anyone know why or how to fix it?

```
function validTime(timestamp) {

  const utcnow = moment.utc().unix();
  if (utcnow > timestamp) {
    return true;
  }
    return false;
}

describe('test time function', () => {
  it('given time should work', () => {
    const t = moment.utc().unix();
    expect(validTime(t)).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Eslint doesn't know that `.to.be.true` are getters with side effects. It just sees a property access that doesn't make sense. Disable the rule in your configuration for the test suite if you want to write tests using this style

Comment: sorry..how should I disable it?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring!

Comment: thank you. find a reference from another post, it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558795/nice-way-to-get-rid-of-no-unused-expressions-linter-error-with-chai/43525402

Comment: will delete this post for duplicated.

Comment: You don't need to delete it, I can just close it :-)