# How to fix warning "eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions"?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, eslint, chai

I'm using [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) to write some unit tests. I'm doing two assertions on an `array` of `strings`. I'm asserting the `array` is an actual `array` & it contains only `strings`. Both assertions are passing & working properly. However, in the second assertion, I'm getting [this warning](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions): `eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions`. I'm unsure of how to fix this warning before ignoring it. How can I accomplish this?

```js
import { assert, expect } from 'chai';
import { prContributors } from './pr-contributors.js';

describe('Pull Request Contributor List array', () => {
  it('should be an array', () => {
    assert.isArray(prContributors, 'prContributors is an array');
  });

  it('should contain only strings', () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
    expect(prContributors.every((contributor) => typeof contributor === 'string')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

I was able to fix it by storing the `results` in a variable & print it, but I don't want to add an unnecessary `console.log()` & I traded a warning for another.

```js
it('should contain only strings', () => {
    const result = prContributors.every((contributor) => typeof contributor === 'string');
    console.log(result); // now I traded the warning :(
});
```

I also try this:

```js
it('should contain only strings', () => {
    const result = prContributors.every((contributor) => typeof contributor === 'string');
    expect(result).to.be.true; // still got the warning
});
```

However, the warning is still there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558795/nice-way-to-get-rid-of-no-unused-expressions-linter-error-with-chai